# R: package ggdendro plotting labels disppear

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggdendro

When I use the great package ggdendro to plot my tree, I come across a problem: One day, all labels of the tree it produces suddenly all disappeared.

When I run the following code in my local machine and in server, I get different results. No labels in local machine and labels do exist in the server version.

```
fit = ClustOfVar::hclustvar(X.quanti = mtcars)

ggdendro::ggdendrogram(as.dendrogram(fit),rotate = TRUE)
```

Server Version(OK):
[image]

Local Windows 7 Version(No labels):
[image]

I printed the session info as well for references.

dput compare(the same)
[image]:

Comment: Can you `dput(ggdendro::ggdendrogram(as.dendrogram(fit),rotate = TRUE))` from both sources?

Comment: @tchakravarty I compared results word by word, no difference.

Comment: After that point, it is only `ggplot` that handles the structure. Barring RStudio Server/Desktop differences, this could only be down to the different versions of `ggplot2` that you have installed.

Comment: Sorry missed that you had added `dput` output.

Comment: @tchakravarty I updated ggplot2 package but it didn't work at all.

Comment: Are you then using `ggplot2_2.1.0` in both cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in the latest development version of ggdendro, [version 0.1.19](https://github.com/andrie/ggdendro/releases)

The underlying issue is described at [issue #24](https://github.com/andrie/ggdendro/issues/24).  This bug was exposed in a change of behaviour in ggplot2, and causes a problem with the `scales` package version 0.4.  To be clear - the bug was in `ggdendro`, not `ggplot2` or `scales`, but never surfaced when using earlier versions of `scales`.

This version is not yet on CRAN, so use `devtools` to get the latest version:

```
devtools::install_github("andrie/ggdendro")
```

---

Update. Version 0.1-20 of `ggdendro` is now available on CRAN.